# What motivates scientists to fabricate results in prestigious journal articles?

Tags: ethics

As is well known, Dr. Obokata was accused and fired for fabricating her paper on STAP cells.

Report on STAP Cell Research Paper Investigation
http://www3.riken.jp/stap/e/c13document52.pdf

I wonder what her motivation was if that is the case.
If STAP cells do not exist, sooner or later her paper will be recognized as invalid by the science community.
However, someone said your scientific paper's being accepted by a prestigious journal would be prestigious enough if it would not be found as a fabrication.

Comment: Please explain the reason for the downvotes. Otherwise I cannot improve my question.

Comment: You are asking us if it is worth cheating and lying to have a paper published in a reputable journal. No academic with self respect will say anything other than no to that.

Comment: I think the headline question is a bit off, "What motivates scientists to fabricate results in prestigious journal articles?" might be better.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the downvotes.  This is a perfectly reasonable, if not important, question whose answer happens to be **OF COURSE NOT!**

Comment: @BillBarth I edited the headline question as you suggested.

Comment: I down-voted because I suspect this question will degenerate the way the previous questions the OP asked about the exact same case did. If the OP used a different example, I would not down vote.

Comment: @jakebeal "*I down-voted because I suspect this question will degenerate the way the previous questions the OP asked about the exact same case did.*"
This is irrational.
Please reset your downvote because it is not degenerated.

Comment: @Johanna I think you misunderstand the question.
I edit it to make it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Only if you're either really [*(really)*](http://blog.chembark.com/2013/08/14/some-very-suspicious-tem-images-in-nano-letters/) stupid or desperate, or naive enough to think that you'll never be found out.

The person in question here seems to have been a [serial offender](http://ajw.asahi.com/article/behind_news/social_affairs/AJ201403160016). And I'd be *very* surprised if anyone who offends so blatantly has no previous history. Fraudsters always start out small and relatively inconspicuous, but confidence and brashness grows until they're caught.

Yes, fraudsters seem attracted by the prospect of fame – but I can't grok why you'd submit a fraudulent paper to *Nature*. Seriously!? Of course you'll be found out! But no, it's not worth it. Ever.

Comment: "*Of course you'll be found out!*"

What if it's a less important result and a less prestigious journal?

Comment: @MakotoKato Then you will probably also be found out, though maybe not as quickly as fewer people will read your paper.

Comment: @Johanna "*Then you will probably also be found out*"

I guess *probably* is one of the points of my question.

Comment: @MakotoKato If anyone at all reads the article, there is a chance you will be found out. That will definitely ruin your career. People who risk their careers on "probably" probably have very short such with sudden ends.

Comment: @MakotoKato if no one is ever going to care about your "research" enough to realise that it is fraudulent, why risk it in the first place? It's always a no-win situation.

Comment: @Moriarty Your numbers go up and you appear to be way more productive than you really are.

Comment: @o4tlulz Sure, until that productivity makes people start reading your papers, because you must have something interesting to say if you so much published...

Comment: As scientists, we are in the business of finding out the reality (or an approximation). Deliberately poisoning the understanding of what is out there, wastes everybody's precious time. I can only imagine two motivations for doing so: 1. someone who makes a mistake which catapults him to unknown fame and is afraid of retracting (I suspect the Schön case is one of these); 2. someone with a type of Münchhausen-like syndrome (I am not a psychiatrist, YMMV). Doing so deliberately (and, if it's important, they **will** be found out), the perpetrator will not ever be believed again.